# Cannot install tomcat6 on CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management, tomcat

I am completely new to CentOS and want to install Tomcat6 however I cannot find it via yum.
Am I missing a repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tomcat6 packages available for CentOS 5 in the standard repositories. CentOS still uses tomcat5. You might find packages out on the internet somewhere.

Comment: tomcat 6 is considered the "unstable" branch,CentOS won't include it unless in the development repos,i guess

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is just a bunch of jar files & shell scripts for the most part, download the tar or zip file to any directory and unpack and use. You dont need to build/install anything.

Comment: O.K. Just wanted to make sure there was no other option I overlooked.
I prefer repositories and security-updates over DIY-installations.

Comment: yes, the nice thing about tomcat though is its not really an install, just an unpack, no make or build or copy to anywhere needed.